# Search function does not find the first element in the struct

Tags: c

I was asked to code a function for class that would allow the user to search through an array of structs.  The function asks the user to enter the ID, and then the other parts of the struct should display if found.  This works perfectly, except for the first element (`[0]`) in the array.  I keep getting a return of -1, or a "not found", and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
int i = 0;
for(; i < totalEng; i++)//loop to find the engine ID
{
    if(search == (peng + i)->id)
        return i;
}

return - 1;
```

This is the search function that works for every ID but this one

```
(peng + 0)->id   = 111;
(peng + 0)->hp   = 500;
(peng + 0)->size = 4.5;
```

This is my function which populates the array:

```
void populateEng(engine* peng)
{
    (peng + 0)->id   = 111;
    (peng + 0)->hp   = 500;
    (peng + 0)->size = 4.5;

    (peng + 1)->id   = 222;
    (peng + 1)->hp   = 120;
    (peng + 1)->size = 1.2;

    (peng + 2)->id   = 333;
    (peng + 2)->hp   = 300;
    (peng + 2)->size = 6.5;

    (peng + 3)->id   = 444;
    (peng + 3)->hp   = 95;
    (peng + 3)->size = 1.5;

    (peng + 4)->id   = 555;
    (peng + 4)->hp   = 200;
    (peng + 4)->size = 2.5;

    (peng + 5)->id   = 666;
    (peng + 5)->hp   = 700;
    (peng + 5)->size = 5.0;
}
```

And this is the search function in its entirety:

```
int searchEng(engine* peng, int totalEng)
{
    char input[5];
    char* pinput = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    int length = 0;
    int search = 0;

    printf("Enter the ID of the engine you wish to search for: ");
    pinput = fgets(input, buffer, stdin);
    length = strlen(input);

    for(; i < length - 1; i++) // making sure the user enters only 3-4 numbers
    {
        if(length > 5 || length < 3)
        {
            i = 0;
            printf("Invalid input. Please enter up to 4 numbers only: ");
            pinput = fgets(input, buffer, stdin);
            length = strlen(input);
        }
        if(input[i] < '0' || input[i] > '9')
        {
            i = 0;
            printf("Invalid input. Please enter up to 4 numbers only: ");
            pinput = fgets(input, buffer, stdin);
            length = strlen(input);
        }
    }

    search = atoi(input); // converting the input into an integer to search

    for(i = 0; i < totalEng; i++)//loop to find the engine ID
    {
        if(search == (peng + i)->id)
            return i;
    }

    return - 1;
}
```

I have the struct and the array defined as this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define buffer 10

struct engine
{
    int id;
    int hp;
    double size;
}typedef engine;

int main()
{
    engine eng[100];
    engine* peng = &eng[0];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I am unable to understand how you are populating the array of structs and then calling the search function. Can you show more code?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I didn't want to post too much code and have it look sloppy. I'm still new to all of this. I'll edit my post now with more information.

Comment: i need to see more part of your code

Comment: Done! Sorry about that I was trying to be modest.

Comment: `length > 5` already UB.

Comment: Also `peng` at caller side : `engine* peng = malloc(6 * sizeof(*peng));` or `engine peng[6];` ?

Comment: BLUEPIXY, I tried commenting that part out of my code and still was unable to find engine ID 111. Can you expand on what you mean by that part of my code being an undefined behavior? I'm using it to make sure the input is no greater than 4 characters plus the enter key. Thanks!

Comment: Because `char input[5];`.

Comment: BLUEPIXY, engine eng[100]; is how I have it in main. Sorry I don't know how to code a comment. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Add your post, not comment.

Comment: and Show us definition of `buffer`.

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Comment: I took the code you presented and finished it as a complete program in what seemed the most natural way.  The result does not exhibit the problem you describe.

Comment: `#define buffer 10` is bad. `fgets(input, buffer, stdin);` should be `fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);` or `fgets(input, 5, stdin);`

Comment: note : `char input[5];` when input by `fgets`. 3 digits  + newline + NUL. if you input 4 digits. 4 digits + NUL. at next time `fgets` receive a newline only.  ==> `i = 0;
    printf("Invalid input. Please enter up to 4 numbers only: ");` : `i = 0;` is wrong. because `i` incremented at loop end.

Comment: `char input[5];` --> `char input[buffer];` (`char input[buffer_size];`)

Comment: `length = strlen(input);

 for(; i < length - 1; i++)` assumes `input[length-1]` is a `'\n'`, yet that is not always true.